# Custom drawing on top of UIButton's background image

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, drawing

What is the method calling sequence of `UIButton`'s drawing?

I have a `UIButton` subclass, let's call it `UIMyButton`. I add it to a .xib controller and give it a background image. Then in the UIMyButton.m file I override `drawRect` method and draw a shape.
Something like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect);
}
```

The problem is that it draws the orange rectangle underneath the background image. What methods are responsible for drawing/updating background images (it updates on "tap down" for example)? How do I force the draw on top without adding an additional custom subview to the button (or is the background image a subview itself)?

I'm just trying to get a clear understanding of how the `UIButton` drawing sequence works.

Comment: hi Bastek - are you there?  Really you should tick the excellent answer below!

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to not use a background for the button. Instead, draw the image inside the drawRect method like so:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
    [image drawInRect:self.bounds];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect); 
}
```